# What does $\bigwedge$ mean in lambda calculus?

Tags: notation, lambda-calculus

In the Wikipedia [article on Fixed-point combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) in the **Values and domains** section, we find the following:

$$x^2 = -1 \implies x = \frac{-1}x \implies fx = \frac{-1}x \bigwedge Yf = x$$

What does the $\bigwedge$ mean? How does $x = \frac{-1}x$ imply $fx = \frac{-1}x \bigwedge Yf = x$? My best guess is observing that $\lambda be.eb = \overline{b^e}$, then guessing that $\bigwedge$ means exponentiation, but that would still not explain why $fx = x$ or $\frac{-1}x \bigwedge Yf = x$.

Comment: This is most probably '$\land$', the logical '*and*' connective.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still confused by $\frac{-1}x \wedge Yf$ in this context.

Comment: Yes, it is *conjunction* (logical and): $\land$. It reads: $fx=\frac {−1}{x} \text { and } \text {Y}f=x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examining the source code of the Wikipedia page indicates that this symbol is generated by `\land`, which denotes "**l**ogical **and**", or conjunction. Note the difference in size and weight between $\bigwedge$ and $\land$.